# Ajax Upload with JQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have a problem with Ajax uploading using Jquery and PHP.. Although there're many stackoverflow posts discussing the same subject, I didn't find one that matches my case.

HTML :

```
<form action="uploadrecord.php" id="upload_record_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <div id="upload_record_form_result"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="file" name="uploadrecord" id="uploadrecord"/></li>
                </ul>
                 <progress></progress>
            </form>

        </div>
```

Javascript :

```
 $('#uploadrecord').live('change', function(event) {

        var formData = new FormData($('#upload_record_form')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: $('#upload_record_form').attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            xhr: function() {  
                myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) { 
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); 
                }
                return myXhr;
            },

            success: completeHandler = function(data) {
                $('#upload_record_form_result').html(data);
            },
            error: errorHandler = function() {
                alert("Failure");
            },
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }, 'json');


    });
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['uploadrecord'])) {
    if ((!empty($_FILES["uploadrecord"])) && ($_FILES['uploadrecord']['error'] == 0)) {

        $filename = basename($_FILES['uploadrecord']['name']);
        $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

        $types = array(
            'video/mp4', 'video/3gpp', 'video/divx', 'video/flv', 'video/mpeg', 'video/mpeg-2', 'video/mpeg4', 'video/mpeg4'
        );

        $type = $_FILES['uploadrecord']['type'];
        if (in_array($type, $types) && $_FILES["uploadrecord"]["size"] < 20000000) {

            $new = sha1(date('Y/m/d H:i:s'));
            $newname = dirname(__FILE__) . '/records/' . $new . '.' . $ext;

            if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadrecord']['tmp_name'], $newname))) {
                echo 'done';
            } else {
                echo 'failed 1';
            }
        }
   } else {
       echo 'failed 2';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Upload failed 3';
}
```

When I try the previous code, and upload a record file, it displays "failed 2", meaning that the "error" code is different from 0.

when I var_dump the array $_FILES['uploadrecord']...this is what I get:

```
array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'Nao Robot.flv' (length=13)
  'type' => string '' (length=0)
  'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
  'error' => int 1
  'size' => int 0
```

I can't figure out, why 'tmp_name' and type are set to empty strings, and why the size is set to 0.

Where's the problem exactly? is it from the client or server side scripting?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should increase your upload_max_filesize?

Comment: thank you , But it displays : 'failed 2', that means it doesn't reach the size conditions at all... it stops with the  "if ((!empty($_FILES["uploadrecord"])) && ($_FILES['uploadrecord']['error'] == 0))"    condition.

Comment: I think I got what you want to say hhh, excuse me for not being carefull, I know ... you mean the php.ini settings, I will try and feed you back

Comment: Your $_FILES[...]['error'] will be 1 if the max filesize is exceeded.

Comment: Thank you so much Dude, it works... I changed it from the php.ini, and Now it's uploading, displaying "Done"..

+1

Comment: Nice! Small hint: you can use .htaccess instead of changing php.ini, easier when you work on different servers/systems. (use php_value upload_max_filesize)

Comment: Yeah, I added it in the .htaccess and that's working Great , thanx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ON MAC OSX:**

1) Go to /etc/php.ini
2) Open the file with **permission** to **write/read**
3) Search for line:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

4)Change to, for example, 6MB ou more:

```
upload_max_filesize = 6M
```

5) Save and restart apache with command:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Those are exactly the steps I did to solve it, I just forgot to add the solution here. (The question was asked back in 2013).

Cheers !

Comment: Oh, sorry for delay. I think that this answer will help others users in the future. Thanks!